# Beautiful Soup : How to extract data from HTML Tags from inconsistent data

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I wanted to extract the data from tags which is coming in two forms :

```
<td><div><font> Something else</font></div></td>
```

and

```
<td><div><font> Something <br/>else</font></div></td>
```

I am using `.string()` method where in the first case it gives me the required string (`Something else`) but in the second case, it gives me `None`.

Is there any better way or alternative way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `.text` property instead of `.string`

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html1 = '<td><div><font> Something else</font></div></td>'
html2 = '<td><div><font> Something <br/>else</font></div></td>'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(html1, 'html.parser')
    div1 = soup1.select_one('div')
    print(div1.text.strip())

    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(html2, 'html.parser')
    div2 = soup2.select_one('div')
    print(div2.text.strip())
```

which outputs:

```
Something else
Something else
```

Comment: I haven't used BeautifulSoup but I had a feeling that there would be a rather simple solution to this problem in the module itself. That's the reason I concluded my answer with that quote. This is indeed the acceptable answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression always for such things!

```
import re
result = re.search('font>(.*?)</font',  str(scrapped_html))
print(result[1])
```

This will work your case. To avoid capturing  tag, you need to manipulate string.

Check via `print("<br/>" in result[1])`, if string contains 
 tag then it'll return `True`, in that case you need to drop the tag.

`result = str(result[1]).split("<br/>")` this will give you a list `[' Something ', 'else']`, join them to get your answer.. `result = (" ").join(result)`

Here is the complete snippet:

```
import re

result = re.search('font>(.*?)</font',  str(scrapped_html))

if "<br/>" in result[1]:
    result = str(result[1]).split("<br/>")
    result = (" ").join(result)
    print(result)
else:
    print(result[1])
```

I understand this is a pretty poor solution, but it'll work for you!